# The javascript game timer does not reload

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

I have recently been working on building a javascript game called "light off" however the one bug I am not able to fix is when the game is over and the user tries to replay or go to the menu, the timer does not start again. I have tried different methods.

```
//start game
fiveMinutes = 60 * .2;
function start() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('game').style.display = 'block';
  });
  score = 0;
    if(fiveMinutes == 60 * .2){
        startTimer(fiveMinutes);
        genartor();
        Score();
    }

}
//=========================================================================================================================\\
//timer
function startTimer(duration) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    if (--timer < 0) {
        game_over();
        return;
    } else if (timer < 1.25) {
      document.getElementById('Onecount').style.display = 'block';
    } else if (timer < 2.5) {
      document.getElementById('Twocount').style.display = 'block';
    } else if (timer < 5) {
      document.getElementById('Three').style.display = 'block';
    } else if (timer < 10) {
      document.getElementById('Four').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function loadTimer() {
  document.getElementById('Onecount').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('Twocount').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('Three').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('Four').style.display = 'none';
  startTimer(fiveMinutes);
}
//=========================================================================================================================\\
// random switcher genartordisplay = document.querySelector('#time');
function genartor() {
  var random = Math.random();
  if (random < 0.5) {
    document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundColor = "#01FF70";
    document.getElementById("two").style.backgroundColor = "#FF4136";
    one_genartor = true;
    two_genartor = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("two").style.backgroundColor = "#01FF70";
    document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundColor = "#FF4136";
    two_genartor = true;
    one_genartor = false;
  }
}
//=========================================================================================================================\\
//scoring sytstem
score = 0;

function Score() {
  var update_score = document.getElementById('scoring');
  update_score.innerHTML = "Score: " + score;

}
//=========================================================================================================================\\
//checking system
function check_one() {
  var one = true;
  if (one == true && one_genartor == true) {
    genartor();
    score = score + 1;
    Score();  
    loadTimer();
  } else if (one == true && one_genartor == false) {
    game_over();
  }
}

function check_two() {
  var two = true;
  if (two == true && two_genartor == true) {
    genartor();
    score = score + 1;
    Score();
    loadTimer();
  } else if (two == true && two_genartor == false) {
    game_over();
  }
}
//=========================================================================================================================\\
//game over function
var gameOver = false;
function game_over() {
gameOver = true;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('game').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('game_Over').style.display = 'block';
  });
  var end_score = document.getElementById('end_Scoring');
  end_score.innerHTML = "Your score was: " + score;
    fiveMinutes = 60 * .2;
}

function replay() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('game_Over').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('game').style.display = 'block';
    start();
      gameOver = false;
  });
}

function menu() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('game_Over').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'block';
      gameOver =false;
  });
}
```

html

```
<html>
<header>
    <title>Light out</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="url.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42103336/web/wow.js"></script>
    <script>
    new WOW().init();

    </script>    

</header>

<body>
  <!-- menu-->
  <div id="menu" class="fadeIn animated">
    <h1>Lights off</h1>
    <button style="display:inline;" id="start" onclick="start();">start</button>

    <p class="makers">Wedde and Stijn</p>

      <!-- social media -->
      <div class="wow bounce animated" data-wow-delay="1s">
          <a href="www.facebook.com">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>
              </a>
          <a href="www.twitter.com">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>
              </a>
          <a href="www.instagram.com">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>
            </a>  
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- game -->
  <div id="game" style="display: none;">
    <div id="scoring"></div>
    <span id="time"></span>
    <div style="display: none;" class="count-down" id="Onecount"></div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="count-down" id="Twocount"></div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="count-down" id="Three"></div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="count-down" id="Four"></div>



    <div id="one" onclick="check_one();"></div>
    <div id="two" onclick="check_two();"></div>

  </div>


  <!-- stop -->
  <div id="game_Over" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Game over</h1>
      <!--link mysql database -->

    <div id="end_Scoring"></div>
    <button id="play_again" onclick="replay();"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i> play again</button>
    <button id="go_menu" onclick="menu();">go to the menu <i class="fa fa-home"></i></button>
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear the interval:

```
var intervalId = 0;
function startTimer(duration) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    if (--timer < 0) {
        game_over();
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        return;
    } else if (timer < 1.25) {
      document.getElementById('Onecount').style.display = 'block';
    } else if (timer < 2.5) {
      document.getElementById('Twocount').style.display = 'block';
    } else if (timer < 5) {
      document.getElementById('Three').style.display = 'block';
    } else if (timer < 10) {
      document.getElementById('Four').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```